# Is Evince a secure way to view malicious PDF?

Tags: security, pdf, evince

I've seen that PDF's can contain malicious Javascript that operates in the background and can do bad things. This is primarily a problem for Adobe Acrobat. However, is this problem also for Evince? I downloaded a PDF from filepi.com, and I'm not sure if it is malicious or not. It's an eBook, and I would really love to keep it, but if it is malicious, I obviously shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

> Is Evince a secure way to view malicious PDF?

Without further restrictions this answer has to be as boring as general: **No**

But you already made some restrictions, which I would like to turn into an assumption and the question which can be inferred from this:

**Assumption**

> The most likely attack vector when it comes to viewing a .pdf file is to exploit the capabilities of embedding and executing Javascript from within .pdf files.

**Question**

> Does Evince reduce the risk of being compromised by viewing a .pdf under this assumption?

**Yes**, because Evince (until now) does not support Javascript in the first place. See: [Does Evince support javascript in pdf files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79049/does-evince-support-javascript-in-pdf-files)

---

**How good/accurate is your assumption?**

This is the upcoming question and more difficult to answer. I would even say it is out of scope of your question. However, here is a list of resources I stumbled across by now:

- Paper:

  - [Combining static and dynamic analysis for the detection of malicious documents](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1972555) (2011)
  - [Techniques for Analysing PDF Malware](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6130668/) (2011)
  - [De-obfuscation and Detection of Malicious PDF Files with High Accuracy](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6480434/?reload=true) (2013)
  - [Looking at the bag is not enough to find the bomb: an evasion of structural methods for malicious PDF files detection](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2484327) (2013)
- Online:

  - [security.stackexchange.com - Can a PDF file contain a virus?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64052/can-a-pdf-file-contain-a-virus)
  - [security.stackexchange.com - How to safely view a malicious PDF?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-to-safely-view-a-malicious-pdf)
  - [sans.org - PDF Malware Overview](https://www.sans.org/security-resources/malwarefaq/pdf-overview) (2010)
  - [hotforsecurity.bitdefender.com - How a boobytrapped PDF file could exploit your Chrome Browser](https://hotforsecurity.bitdefender.com/blog/how-a-boobytrapped-pdf-file-could-exploit-your-chrome-browser-and-its-not-adobes-fault-14122.html) (2016)

Answer (score 1):

Attacks on non-executable files rarely exploit the api. It is much more common to attack a weakness in the viewer. It would be unlikely although not impossible for such a error to exists in both Adobe and Evince. To be safe you could setup a virtual environment (I recommend the free Virtualbox)